# Python Type Error: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python

Was coding a new slot machine programe using python, and when I run the code it gave me the error in the title:

```
def main():
    balance = deposit()
    lines = nb_lines()
    while True:
        bet = gbet()
        tbet = bet * lines

        if tbet >= balance:
            print(f"Not enough money! Balance: + ${balance}")
        else:
            break
```

And here is the gbet() function:

```
def gbet():
    while True:
        amount = input("Bet Amount: ")
        if amount.isdigit():
            amount = int(amount)
            if MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
                break
            else:
                print(f"Choose a number that is between ${MIN_BET} - ${MAX_BET}.\n")
        else:
            print("Please enter a number!\n")
```

I did run the code in my terminal the first 3 questions worked but when I got to the part where it tells the user about the Bet, Balance, Lines it gave me the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Comment: `gbet` does not return anything, so it doesn't give `bet` variable any value (i.e. default of `None`).

Comment: As an aside... Are you aware that just because str.isdigit() returns True doesn't mean that it can be converted to *int* ?

Comment: What value do you expect `bet` to have after running `bet = gbet()`? The value that you are calling `amount` inside of `gbet`? If so, you need to return that value so that `bet` can receive it.

Comment: @bl4ze That still won't help you. `amount` inside `gbet` will be a different variable than the one inside `main`. You need to explicitly `return` a value from `gbet`.

Comment: @matszwecja Added `return amount` inside the `gbet()` function and it did work, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

The *gbet()* function needs to return a value. It should also validate the input value to check that it represents an int as well as being within range.

Something like this:

```
MIN_BET = 10
MAX_BET = 1_000

def gbet():
    while True:
        amount = input('Bet amount: ')
        try:
            if MIN_BET <= (bet := int(amount)) <= MAX_BET:
                return bet
            print(f'\aChoose a number between {MIN_BET} and {MAX_BET}')
        except ValueError:
            print('\aPlease enter an integer amount')
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using the break functionality, return the function there.
Code:

```
if MIN_BET <= amount <= MAX_BET:
    return amount
```